# unable to cover batch class completely

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, scheduled-apex

Scheduler Class:

```
global class bankerjob implements Database.batchable<sObject> , Database.Stateful{
private EmailTemplate emailTemp;
global bankerjob(){
    emailTemp = [Select Id From EmailTemplate Where Name = 'Banker']; 
}
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    String query = 'Select Id, Lastname, Firstname, Email From Contact WHERE (Id IN (select Banker__c from Lead WHERE RecordType.Name = \'Branch\' ) AND RecordType.Name = \'Branch\')'; 
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}   
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Contact> scope){        
    try{
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for(Contact con : scope) {
         if(emailTemp != null && con.Email != null && con.Email != '') {
               Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
               email.setToAddresses(new List<String>{con.Email});
               email.setTargetObjectId(con.Id);                     
               email.setTemplateId(emailTemp.Id);
               email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(true);        
               emails.add(email);
         }  
     }
     Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
     }
     catch(exception ex){}
}   
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){}
}
```

Test Class:

```
@istest
class bankerjob_Test{        
static testmethod void test() {     
  Profile p = [select Name from profile where Name = 'System 
  Administrator'];           
  User u = new User(Alias = 'test1',Country='United 
  States',Email='abc@domain.com',EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', 
                       LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',LocaleSidKey='en_US',ProfileId = p.Id,                               
                       TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='abc@test.org');
  insert u;
  system.runas(u){
     List<contact> con1 = new List<Contact>();
          for(Integer i=0 ;i <200;i++){
              Contact con = new Contact();
              con.Lastname = 'testing1'+i;
              con.Email = 'test@email.com';
              con1.add(con);
          }        
          insert con1;

          List<Lead> lead1 = new List<Lead>();
          for(Integer j=0 ;j <200;j++){
              Lead l = new Lead();
              l.LastName = 'test';
              l.Status = 'New';
              l.banker__c = con1[0].Id;
              lead1.add(l);        
          }
          insert lead1; 

          EmailTemplate emailTemp = new EmailTemplate();
          emailTemp.isActive = true;
          emailTemp.Name = 'name';
          emailTemp.DeveloperName = 'test';
          emailTemp.TemplateType = 'text';
          emailTemp.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId();              
          insert emailTemp;

          System.Test.startTest();
          bankerjob obj = new bankerjob();
          DataBase.executeBatch(obj);
          System.Test.stopTest();             
  }   
  } 
  }
```

Unable to cover the global void execute method. 
Please let me know what am I missing here, any suggestion helps! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fulfill the query conditions. That means you need to create lead records and specify those contacts as Banker__c values for those leads, and set the correct record type for all of the leads and contacts you create. Once you create records that meet the criteria, your execute method will run.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, I had included the Lead it is still not covering the test class.

Comment: @Sfdclearner Oh, I forgot to mention you need to use the correct record types.

Comment: sorry I too forgot about record type. It's working now, thanks!